# Modify regex to match various ISO language codes

Tags: java, regex

I have these strings that I want to match using a regex:

- `es-us`
- `fr` (0 dashes)
- `fr-ca` (1 dash)
- `xx-xx-xx` (2 dashes)

I have a starting point of a regex as: `([a-z])+-([a-z])+-([a-z])+` which matches the xx-xx-xx example above, but strings with 1 dash or less is excluded.  So, how can i make it so that it ALSO matches `fr-ca` or `fr` or `en-us` in the above examples? NOTE: ALL characters should be allowed, not just `fr-ca` or `fr`

Comment: `[a-z][a-z](-[a-z][a-z](-[a-z][a-z])?)?` You are missing the optional condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a duplicate, but I'm not sure what I'd be searching for. Either way here's a simple answer: `^[a-zA-Z]{2}(?:-[a-zA-Z]{2}){0,2}$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UYJy9Y/5)

Comment: unfortunately, this would also match xx-xx-xx-xx or more dashes.  Also, what was the point of the non-capturing group?

Comment: @KevinWelker It would... what is the limit? 3? The non capture group is there so I can use `*` to repeatedly match it

Comment: I updated my answer to only allow up to 3 `xx` patterns

Answer (score 1):

To also have matching case for any segment, use:

```
^([a-z]{2}|[A-Z]{2})(?:-([a-z]{2}|[A-Z]{2})){0,2}$
```